SignOut - Session is not deleted - Reconnect to the fresh signOut user
We have a project built with Next.JS / Nextauth that uses Identity Server V4 to handle SignIn/SignOut of a user.
We have a problem with the disconnected part of a user. When we click on the SignOut (1) button it called the signOut function that redirect on the signIn button with Identity Server 4(2).


The problem is that on signOut part the session is not deleted, causing on the new connect to reconnect the user with the cookie session that was not deleted.
Or we want to access to the form to login (3) not being automaticly reconnected to the user session.

In the documentation of NextAuth.js it says that when we pass the redirect parameter with the false value, it should "destroy" the current session and avoid redirect.
In our code we have a button that calls a handler function to execute all the parameters given in the function :
It Doesn't seem like the signOut takes the parameters givens even if I put a callback as the parameter not present in the screen (code here below).
export async function signOutHandler() {
    //signOut({ redirect: true, callbackUrl: '/login' });
}

So I want to have an instruction line that tells IS4 to suppress my session before or after processing signOut.
Or is there another way to destroy the session in my function before redirecting to signOut ?
So when we do reconnect we don't come back to the user that has just disconnected.
Thanks for the help.
Ach.
We tried :

The SignOut method with parameter redirect false and callback URL doesn't work
I tried to suppress the cookies with pure JS but they are secured so it doesn't work.

What we expect :

A line in our function that could delete IS4 session when executed.
A way to make the SignOut function do the delete that it should do natively but don't.
Any other solution to fix that is welcomed..


The session is stored in the cookies and do check if the expected cookies are removed after signout or not.
